# Как объединить (просуммировать) данные в столбце по id?

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица со следующими данными:

```
ID       Value
1          4
1          5
2          8
3          10
```

Как мне получить данные в таком формате?

```
id         Value
3          10
1          9
2          8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил так

```
SELECT id, SUM(value) as rall
FROM table
GROUP BY id order by rall desc
```